# WooCommerce Product Vendors How to Add Menu Link for Vendor Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress with the WooCommerce Product Vendors plugin. The vendor dashboard shows different items than the admin dashboard. I would like to add a new menu item on the vendors dashboard. I cannot find the hook / function to add it. Can someone help me add it using the functions.php file?